# Is apparmor preventing the running of my application?

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor, tails-os

I have an application that runs on Ubuntu and used to run on Tails. But now with Tails 1.5 it does not run anymore on Tails.

My application package is basically a directory containing the application, a shell script application.sh and a number of non-standard libraries (Qt). When I run the script in a root terminal I get the error that the application cannot be found at the location the script tells that the application is. The problem is that the application is exactly present (and executable) at that location. For instance with the file manager or with "ls" I see that the file is there.

I contacted the Tails people and they tell me it could well be apparmor causing this.

How can I find out what is causing this problem? I could not find anything useful in the log files, although I do not exactly know what I have to look for.

Comment: If apparmor's causing it, it will log to `/var/log/syslog` (or to the journal in the systemd world). Grep for `apparmor` in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I used your suggestion to find out that apparmor was not the origin of my problem. So I went on and found the solution and it runs again on Tails. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! Could you please post the actual problem and what you did as an answer, to help future users?

Comment: It is quite embarrassing. I used the 64bit version of my app. And Tails is 32bit only.

Comment: You wrote "..does not run anymore on Tails", but *did it ever run on Tails?*